# How do I scrape divs with multiple classes using Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I've looked for answers on this site but I didn't get anything that worked for me. I'm trying to scrape the Top Picks page in IMDB and I want to get the href of the "a" tag.
[This is what the HTML of the page I'm trying to scrape looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdqt3.jpg). I've hovered over the element that I want to scrape. I'm using the scrapy shell to test but I'm just getting a list of size 0. I've tried:

```
movies = response.css('a.ipc-poster-card__title').get()

movies = response.css('div[role="group"]').getall() # to get the div first so I can work my way down to the <a> tag

movies = response.css('a.ipc-poster-card__title.ipc-poster-card__title--clamp-2.ipc-poster-card__title--clickable').get()
```

and multiple other lines too.
I tried the last one because I read online that spaces are seen as hierarchy by scrapy and I should use a "." for multiple classes instead, but all I'm getting are either lists of size 0 when I type *len(movies)* or I'm getting movies as a *None* object. How can I get the href from that "a" tag?

Comment: Hey, I think you are parsing the incorrect page. in scrapy shell use ```from scrapy.shell import open_in_browser
open_in_browser(response)
```
and probably you will check that you're parsing an incomplete page.

Comment: @Joaquin Yeah I think you're right. This is what I wrote on the shell:
`from scrapy.shell import open_in_browser`
`fetch("https://imdb.com")`
`top_picks = response.css('div.top-picks a::attr(href)')`
`top_picks_url = response.urljoin(top_picks)`
`fetch(top_picks_url)`
`open_in_browser(response)`

and all I get is the Top Picks page template with the movies still loading. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: It happens because it renders javascript, you'll need to use some tool to render it(splash, selenium, etc). Another option is to find the xhr request and parse it directly.

Comment: To get help in this new issues you can update your quesiton or close this one and create another question.

Comment: I'll look up xhr requests, and if that doesn't work then I'll update the question. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Joaquin pointed out in the comments, I'm going to be using Selenium and Splash now.